# Qt: Properly integrating undo framework with QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, undo, qgraphicsscene

I'm writing a Qt app that is based around a `QGraphicsScene` canvas with movable shapes on it, and I'm trying to integrate undo-redo functionality. For most functions like creation and deletion of shapes it's fairly trivial to implement on the `QGraphicsScene` itself, but I want elements to be movable and for the movement to be undoable. Right now I'm using the rubber band dragmode on the scene and the `ItemIsSelectable` and `ItemIsMovable` flags on the items. The problem is that there seems to be no good place to create the `QUndoCommand` to represent shape movement. If I do it within the `QGraphicsScene::itemChange` method, then selecting and moving two or more shapes results in separate undo commands for different objects being interleaved and thus are not able to be merged, so undoing results in unexpected behaviour. There's no event in the `QGraphicsScene` that gets called when its items are moved around that I can see, so I'm kind of stuck.

The worst case scenario that I see is that I disable the `ItemIsMovable` flag on my custom `QGraphicsItem` objects and handle movement entirely in the `QGraphicsScene` mouse events, but reimplementing that functionality properly seems quite complicated (I checked how Qt does it internally and there is quite a lot of code for handling complicated cases, such as where an object and some of its children are both selected). This seems like the most obvious of use cases for the undo stack (so much so that the example program for the undo framework is a `QGraphicsScene` program much like mine, except without multiple object movement support) so it seems weird that there's no built-in way to do it without reimplementing a significant part of the core functionality. Does anyone have any insights or examples of programs that do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this somewhat hackishly I think. I added a `preMovePoint` property to my custom shapes and in the `mousePressedEvent` of the `QGraphicsScene`, I set the `preMovePoint` of each of the selected shapes to their respective current positions, and in `mouseReleaseEvent`, created a composite move command from the `preMovePoint` to the current `pos` of each shape. I would still be interested in knowing if there's a better way.

Comment: I came up with a similarly hackish fix involving a previous location stack in each `QGraphicsItem` and then pushing the items that were changed to the undo stack.  It is ugly but it works.  Thanks for the question and answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's hackish since this is how it is implemented in the official Qt example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-undoframework-example.html